# 'Bad file descriptor' when using forwarded gpg-agent socket on Linux

Tags: ssh, gnupg, yubikey, gpg-agent

I'm using gpg4win on my Windows client to sign commits to Git with my Yubikey. This is working fine and I'm trying to accomplish the same on a remote Linux machine by forwarding my S.gpg-agent.extra socket on Windows to my remote Linux machine, using SSH. I used [this](https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding) guide to accomplish this.

The socket forwarding seems to work as I can see the socket on my remote Linux machine. However, executing something like `gpg --list-secret-keys` on my remote Linux machine returns:

```
connect to /c/Users/martijn/AppData/Local/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra port -2 failed: Bad file descriptor
```

I've added the following host configuration to my .ssh/config file in my Windows home:

```
Host my-remote-host.net
    HostName        my-remote-host.net
    User            martijn
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    RemoteForward   /run/user/8898/gnupg/S.gpg-agent /c/Users/martijn/AppData/Local/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
    ExitOnForwardFailure yes
```

Besides the GPG issue, the SSH tunnel itself is fully functional. I also verified that the S.gpg-agent.extra file exists in the given directory. Please feel free to ask for more information, if necessary.

What am I doing wrong?